# Can 4 microservices with there own Dockerfiles and YML files have Nginx as reverse proxy with its own Dockerfile and YML file

Tags: microservices, nginx-reverse-proxy

Is possible to have 4 microservices that have there own Dockerfile and YML have Nginx as a reverse proxy with its own  Dockerfile and YML also .Everything being connected to the same docker network and deployed on same server

**BACKEND **

Microservices 1
-Laravel project files
-Dockerfile
-Docker-compose.yml

Microservices 2
-Laravel project files
-Dockerfile
-Docker-compose.yml

Microservices 3
-Laravel project files
-Dockerfile
-Docker-compose.yml

**FRONTEND**

Micoservice 4
-Nextjs
-Dockerfile
-Docker-compose.yml

**Then Reverse Proxy**

Nginx
-nginx.conf
-Dockerfile
-Docker-compose.yml

Tried it but failed for it to work becuase the only way i know how is when the reverse proxy and microservices share the same yml